# How to render local json file into HTML and browser

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am pretty new in Javascript and I have problem. Currently I am working on project, that is actually my practice project and I'm trying to make shopping cart page. My problem is with JSON file, I don't know how to render it (show it within HTML in browser), I have local JSON file with some products. Here is my code of main page, app.js(where is my function for JSON file) and JSON file with products

HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Shopping Cart</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="cobe" />
  <meta name="author" content="cobe" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <main class="main-wrapper">

    <div class="items">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="" alt="" class="img">Image</img>
        </div>
        <h2 class="item-name">Name of item</h2>
        <h3 class="price">Price</h3>
        <button class="button">Add item</button>
      </div>
      <div id="products" class="list"></div>
    </div>
</main>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="../products.json"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../app.js"></script>
```

app.js file

```
let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    let response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
    let products = response.products;

    let output = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
      output += '<li>' + products[i].name + '</li>';
    }
    document.getElementById('products').innerHTML = output;
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "products.json", true);
xhttp.send();
```

and JSON file which is called products.json

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Eggs",
      "image": "https://d17zv3ray5yxvp.cloudfront.net/variants/W1ymDizfe679XsfX9uP8A5bU/7b27a910a7194c812eacf34700e38dcab3abed02f30837d1dad313c5651bb5fa",
      "price": {
        "amount": 7.99,
        "currency": "Kn",
        "measureUnit": "Kom"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "image": "https://d17zv3ray5yxvp.cloudfront.net/variants/b1qEMnNGbwiwV5cWysofPoqz/7b27a910a7194c812eacf34700e38dcab3abed02f30837d1dad313c5651bb5fa",
      "name": "Milk",
      "price": {
        "amount": 4.99,
        "currency": "Kn",
        "measureUnit": "Kom"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "image": "https://d17zv3ray5yxvp.cloudfront.net/variants/1avpwnxKAEqEpTf1k3VCbBbg/7b27a910a7194c812eacf34700e38dcab3abed02f30837d1dad313c5651bb5fa",
      "name": "Cheese",
      "price": {
        "amount": 44.99,
        "currency": "Kn",
        "measureUnit": "Kg"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So my question is what should I write in HTML file so I could get let's say name of product from JSON file into my div which is declared in HTML file for name or am I missing some more JS functions? Currently my page is blank because I couldn't resolve how to get everything from JSON file.

HTML files are in views folder, app.js and products.json are outside of views folder.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a function to generate the template and set the [innerHTML](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) property.

You can use this `populateProducts` function once you have got the response `JSON` from the API. This will generate the template and will update the DOM.

```js
var myData = {
  "products": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Eggs",
      "image": "https://d17zv3ray5yxvp.cloudfront.net/variants/W1ymDizfe679XsfX9uP8A5bU/7b27a910a7194c812eacf34700e38dcab3abed02f30837d1dad313c5651bb5fa",
      "price": {
        "amount": 7.99,
        "currency": "Kn",
        "measureUnit": "Kom"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "image": "https://d17zv3ray5yxvp.cloudfront.net/variants/b1qEMnNGbwiwV5cWysofPoqz/7b27a910a7194c812eacf34700e38dcab3abed02f30837d1dad313c5651bb5fa",
      "name": "Milk",
      "price": {
        "amount": 4.99,
        "currency": "Kn",
        "measureUnit": "Kom"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "image": "https://d17zv3ray5yxvp.cloudfront.net/variants/1avpwnxKAEqEpTf1k3VCbBbg/7b27a910a7194c812eacf34700e38dcab3abed02f30837d1dad313c5651bb5fa",
      "name": "Cheese",
      "price": {
        "amount": 44.99,
        "currency": "Kn",
        "measureUnit": "Kg"
      }
    }
  ]
};

function populateProducts() {
  var template = '';
  for(let index = 0; index < myData.products.length; index++) {
    template += 
    "<div>Name: " + myData.products[index].name + "</div>" + 
    "<div>Image: <img class='my-image' src='" + myData.products[index].image + "' /></div>"+
    "<div>Amount: " + myData.products[index].price.amount + "</div>" + 
    "<div>Currency: " + myData.products[index].price.currency + "</div>" + 
    "<div>MeasureUnit: " + myData.products[index].price.measureUnit + "</div>";
  }
  document.getElementById('item-wrapper').innerHTML = template;
}

populateProducts();
```

```css
.my-image {
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<main class="main-wrapper">
  <div id="item-wrapper"></div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use a templating system such as [Handlebars.js](https://handlebarsjs.com/), you could convert the repeated part of your HTML (the item div) into a template and then populate it with the data. Adapting the 'Getting Started' example from the Handlebars page, the template would look something like:

```
<script id="item-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#each products}}
    <div class="item">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="{{image}}" alt="" class="img">Image</img>
      </div>
      <h2 class="item-name">{{name}}</h2>
      <h3 class="price">{{price.amount}}</h3>
      <button class="button">Add item</button>
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

Then in the script you would register the template:

```
const source = document.getElementById("item-template").innerHTML;
const template = Handlebars.compile(source);
```

...and then inside your HTTP request, you can pass the data to the template and it'll return HTML which you can add to the DOM as you wish:

```
const html = template(context);
```